# Asp.net Crawler Webresponse Operation Timed out

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-crawler, httpwebresponse

Hi I have built a simple threadpool based web crawler within my web application. Its job is to crawl its own application space and build a Lucene index of every valid web page and their meta content. Here's the problem. When I run the crawler from a debug server instance of Visual Studio Express, and provide the starting instance as the IIS url, it works fine. However, when I do not provide the IIS instance and it takes its own url to start the crawl process(ie. crawling its own domain space), I get hit by operation timed out exception on the Webresponse statement. Could someone please guide me into what I should or should not be doing here? Here is my code for fetching the page. It is executed in the multithreaded environment.

```
private static string GetWebText(string url)
    {
        string htmlText = "";        

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.UserAgent = "My Crawler";

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    htmlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return htmlText;
    }
```

And the following is my stacktrace:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at CSharpCrawler.Crawler.GetWebText(String url) in c:\myAppDev\myApp\site\App_Code\CrawlerLibs\Crawler.cs:line 366
   at CSharpCrawler.Crawler.CrawlPage(String url, List`1 threadCityList) in c:\myAppDev\myApp\site\App_Code\CrawlerLibs\Crawler.cs:line 105
   at CSharpCrawler.Crawler.CrawlSiteBuildIndex(String hostUrl, String urlToBeginSearchFrom, List`1 threadCityList) in c:\myAppDev\myApp\site\App_Code\CrawlerLibs\Crawler.cs:line 89
   at crawler_Default.threadedCrawlSiteBuildIndex(Object threadedCrawlerObj) in c:\myAppDev\myApp\site\crawler\Default.aspx.cs:line 108
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

Thanks and cheers,
Leon.

Comment: Maybe its not find the web adress that you pass on ? Did you have check it out ? If you pass an adress that can not locate, then its wait for connection until get the timeout.

Comment: Hi Aristos, yes I have confirmed that the page I pass is "browsable". However, like I said, when the crawler runs on its own server space, I too, cant access any sites on the server. Get a 403 too many users message. But having said that, this issue does not reproduce when I try to run the crawler for another server instance than its own.

Comment: Hi, @Leon I am also facing the same issue have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

How many concurrent requests are being made by your crawler?  You could easily be starving the threadpool - particularly as the crawler is running within the website code.

Each Request that your calling like this will use 2 threads from the pool - one to process the request and another to wait for the response.

Comment: I have now gone on and tried playing with max threads and disposing off everything im using along with HttpWebResponse. No luck. I cannot seem to figure why my crawler is able to crawl the exact same site from the debugger in Visual Studio, but crawling the IIS instance; and not be able to crawl "itself", ie, crawl the debug instance of the server from the debugger or the IIS instance, when the crawler is run from the IIS.